# Viewpager on fragment having issues with connecting pageadapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

```
class main_fragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        lateinit var view: ViewPager
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_fragment, container, false)

        val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)
        viewPager.adapter = PageAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        val tabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout)
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }
}
```

i made a pageradapter but when i try and connect it doesn't work

i get an error saying unresolved referance:supportFragmentManager

if anyone could help me it would be much appreciated

Comment: You can try childFragmentManager or fragmentManager = (activity as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager

Answer (score 1):

first, you try to init your adapter after a return which means will never be executed.
the solution is:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
   viewPager.adapter = PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

}
```

Comment: ok thanks. now i'm having a problem with this. i deleted ''' lateinit var view: ViewPager''' this code and now it says that only non-null asserted calles are allowed on reciver type view

Comment: @PuzzleHead can you show your  fragment class ?